# How do you know which Controller to use when multiple models are displayed on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

For example, consider a forum's homepage:

```
Category 
  Forum 
  Forum 
Category 
  Forum 
  Forum 
Category
  Forum
```

Should the root path point to `categories#index` because you're populating `@categories` and then looping through the forums for each category in the view?

Or should the root path point to `forums#index` because, more conceptually, the purpose of this index is to showcase the forums and the categories are only used to organize what really amounts to a list of forums?

Answer (score 0):

Mentally (and technically) the Category object can be reduced to an attribute on the Forum model. Also, you are better of querying for the Forums and then "grouping" them per category.

So in this case this view belongs to the Forum controller.